# Non-Canonical Clauses, Complete Sentences (Interrogatives[?])?

Tags: interrogatives

In clauses, I thought a clause contains a verb and an argument. That may seem like canonical clauses(?). In non-canonical clauses I guess they may still get called complete sentences (interrogatives[?]), maybe mostly non-canonical (complete[?]) (sentences[?]) interrogatives?

In

> what about Sir Isaac Newton

or

> What about you?

I guess non-canonical clauses may not request a subject verb object? Do they mostly got to mostly contain a  wh-word and maybe some phrase after?

Comment: In speech, the intonation pattern alone is sufficient to "mark" the statement as such a question.  Intoned as a question, *and Newton?* could mean "And what about Newton?" or "How about Newton?"

Comment: You have a set of grammar terms that seems to me a hotchpotch of different linguistic schools. Perhaps you should ask your question on Linguistics.